# variables declared in @implementation

Tags: objective-c

I'm working through a code listing from a book and it has a pair of variables (specifically NSString *) declared and initialised in the @implementation rather than the @interface but outside of any method body. I've not seen this before and I'm wondering what the difference this makes in scope and so on.

I've had a quick look in The Objective C Programming Language but I can't see anything describing what effect this has.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: will you post as code sample that shows what you're talking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables declared inside @implementation have global scope.

If you declare them as "static", they are only visible from the methods in the same source file.

So:

```
@implementation MyClass

NSString *myString; // global scope, and accessible by all code in your project
```

or

```
@implementation MyClass

static NSString *myString; // global scope, but only accessible by code 
                           // in this source file
```

Comment: I was searching for answer and realized that if its in bracelet, then it's actually ivar.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785765/instance-variables-declared-in-objc-implementation-file

Comment: are you sure about that ?? I can't make it work. Perhaps you made wrong comments

Comment: What's the difference between defining them outside the `@implementation` block or inside it?