# Objective C: ARC with IVars declared in implementation file

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, instance-variables, objective-c-2.0

I found an interesting [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785765/instance-variables-declared-in-objc-implementation-file) describing how, in Objective-C 2.0, instance variables can be declared in the implementation file.  Consider this example:

```
@interface MyClass {}
@end

@implementation MyClass {    
  NSObject *obj1;
  NSObject *obj2;
}
@end
```

Notice the ivars `obj1` and `obj2` are *not* declared properties.  Since they are not declared with an `@property` statement, there are no corresponding ownership qualifiers such as `weak`/`strong`.

My question is, will a project using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) remember to clean up objects declared in this manner?  Any documents addressing this specific issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, these implicitly have a `__strong` in front of them. ARC will deal with them just as you'd expect from a strong property. The appropriate section in the docs is [`4.4.1. Objects`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects).