# Got stuck when deploy app on iphone

Tags: ios

I got stuck when I try to deploy the test app on my device.
When I click run on XCode, the device is going to run the application. However, it stuck in the first view. And nothing is moving.
I was wondering if there is something wrong. Is it caused by jailbreak? My ios version is 5.0.1.
Then someone tell me what I could do to solve it.

Comment: Do you get any msg on the log?

Comment: nope. Just stopped at the first view

Comment: With stuck you mean freezed? Or that you dont see anything?

Comment: check if the frame of your view is correctly set. if clipsToBounds is NO (default), subviews are displayed outside of the frame-rect but touch handling is not done

Comment: @MartinUllrich it doesn't make sense. I mean, it could work fine in the simulator. Why it can't on device.

Comment: i had this problem a couple of times.. other approach: change the debugger to gdb if it is set to lldb

Comment: Thanks @MartinUllrich. I will try immediately after I click the Add Comment Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strange launch issues when debugging with LLDB.

Try using GDB instead

(EDIT) Latest Xcode 4.3 update with LLDB-112 should fix a lot of problems (but there are still bugs including [reading of ivars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579650/using-arc-my-ivars-are-null-after-init))