# iOS - What is happening with my instance variables?

Tags: ios, debugging, variables, int

I have a really simple class, and within the implementation I have this code:

```
@implementation MyProgram
{
    int myInt;
}
```

Then in a separate method I have this:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    myInt = 0;
}
```

I noticed this int was giving me problems, so I debugged and stopped it within myMethod. When I hover over the variable, it tells me the following information:

```
int    $3    17893987392
```

Obviously, this information (I think) should look like this:

```
int    myInt    0
```

Strange thing is, when I re-hover over the variable, the "name" continues to increment by one:

```
int    $4    17893987392
```

Can someone shed some light on what is going on?? I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1 yesterday, and things have been strange ever since.

Comment: What constitutes 'debugging'?

Comment: Adding a breakpoint at the relevant line within myMethod and seeing what the value of myInt is before and after it is assigned the value of 0.

Comment: NSLog your int and return it's value.  That's what you should care about...

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? This might help. XCode may have some intermediate stuff in there. Also, I find that scattering a few NSLogs in there does help sometimes with weird errors like this, not only to give you insight, but they may also force the compiler to recreate object code surrounding the trouble spot and thus clear things up. P.S. I deleted my original answer because I realized it wasn't what you're after.

Comment: Try to define instance variable in interace section, instead of implementation.

Comment: Perhaps you can try initializing your int in the init method in the .m file. I find that sometime if I leave an iVar uninitialized it behaves weirdly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the LLVM debugger -- change your debugger to GDB.  See [UIViewController subclass can't assign instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482689/uiviewcontroller-subclass-cant-assign-instance-variable) for more information.