# Objective-c and Xcode strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In xcode 4.3.1, target iPad 5.1 simulator

- create a single view app
- use ARC, don't use Storyboard
- in ViewController.h

  ```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface ViewController : UIViewController
  {
          NSObject *anObject;
          NSObject *anotherObject;
  }

  -(void) makeObjects;

  @end
  ```
- in ViewController.m add

  ```
  -(void) makeObjects{
          anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
          anotherObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

          int a = 1;
  }
  ```
- in AppDelegate.m add a line

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
          self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
          // Override point for customization after application launch.
          self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
          self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

          [self.viewController makeObjects]; // ADD THIS LINE  <--------

          [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
          return YES;
  }
  ```
- in ViewController.m, set a breakpoint at

  ```
  anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  ```
- run
- step over breakpoint
- anObject = 0x00000000, anotherObject is set!

Comment: I like what you've done with the formatting. Makes it very interesting to read :)

Comment: Lol Rob, this was my first post on Stackoverflow. I have not formatted the text at all, simply copy and paste:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the LLDB debugger?  Currently it doesn't give you correct values on iVars in the simulator.  Switch back to GDB and you'll find the correct values reported.  I discovered this behavior here: [UIViewController subclass can't assign instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482689/uiviewcontroller-subclass-cant-assign-instance-variable).

And yes, I reported a bug.  I got a response back from Apple stating it is a known issue.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I was using LLDB.