# Calling Obj-C Code from JavaScript via Console: Arguments get dropped?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

Having a heck of a time with this one.

I've got a super-simple Cocoa app containing one WebView, a WebScripting API defined in the page, and a single NSObject defined on that API.  When I turn on the debugger tools (in the embedded WebView), I can see the API on the JavaScript window object, and I can see my "api" property defined on that -- but when I call the API's "get" method, the arguments aren't being serialized -- when the Obj-C method gets called, the arguments are missing.  See below, which hopefully illustrates:

[image]

I've combed through the docs, I've (apparently) set the appropriate methods to expose everything that needs to be exposed, and I can see the method being called.  There has to be something stupid I'm missing, but as a relative newbie to this environment, I'm not seeing it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like when I call these methods from script within a page loaded by the WebView, things look okay.  It's only when I invoke the JavaScript methods with the developer tools that the arguments get dropped.  Again, methods get called, breakpoints get hit (in Xcode), but no arguments.  Stumped.

Comment: Have you tried changing get:(NSString *)input to get:(id)input and setting a breakpoint (not NSLog) just to see if anything is coming across?

Comment: Can we please see some of the javascript code as well?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set WebKitDeveloperExtras to YES in your default user defaults when you send -[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]?

Comment: Just tried that to be sure -- no dice.  Argh!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of Xcode you're using you could be getting a known error.  If you're using LLDB on anything but the most recent version, it might not be giving you the right variables in the debugger.  The solution has been to use GDB instead of LLDB until Apple fixes the problem.  But I think they fixed the problem in the latest version.  I'd change the debugger to use GDB and see if you're getting the right variables in Xcode. (Product-> Edit Scheme...-> Run  -> Debugger).  I came across this problem in iOS, though, so I don't know its applicability to OSX.  Worth a try anyway.

I originally came across the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485349/1147934

Comment: Damnedest thing, but that doesn't seem to work, either.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I process javascript in the main thread of my app from a local file stored in the apps directory. I check for beginning and ending tokens for the js functions I am executing and whether the function contains a variable.

Hopefully this can give you some good ideas for your issue. You could also do alerts in the js to see if the values post correctly as you run the app (I am sure you thought of that already, but it's worth mentioning.) Happy coding! I hope this helps!

in the .h file define:

```
NSMutableString *processedCommand;
NSArray *commandArguments;
```

In the .m file:

```
// tokens
#define kOpenToken @"<%%"
#define kCloseToken @"%%>"

// this will throw
-(void)executeJScriptCommand:(NSString *)aCommand {

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(executeThisCommand:) withObject:aCommand waitUntilDone:YES];
}

// this will throw 
-(NSString *)executeCommand:(NSString *)command {

NSString *aCommand = [[[command stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:kOpenToken withString:@""] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:kCloseToken withString:@""] 
                      stringByTrimmingLeadingAndTrailingWhitespaces];

if ([aCommand hasPrefix:@"="])
{
    // variable. get value
    [self getVariableFromCommand:aCommand]; 
}
else {
    [self executeThisCommand:aCommand];
}

NSString *returnValue = [NSString stringWithString:processedCommand];

self.processedCommand = nil;
self.commandArguments = nil;

return returnValue;
}

-(void)executeThisCommand:(NSString *)aCommand {

BOOL hasError = NO;

// clear result
self.processedCommand = nil;
self.commandArguments = nil;

BOOL isFromJS = NO;
NSString *function = nil;
NSMutableArray *commandParts = nil;

@try {
    // first, break the command into its parts and extract the function that needs to be called, and the (optional) arguments
    commandParts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[aCommand componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]];
    if ([[[commandParts objectAtIndex:0] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"js-call"]) {
        isFromJS = YES;
        [commandParts removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // get our function, arguments
    function = [[commandParts objectAtIndex:0] retain];
    [commandParts removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    if ([commandParts count] > 0){
        if (isFromJS == YES) {
            NSString *arguments = [[commandParts objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if ([arguments length] > 0) {
                self.commandArguments = [arguments JSONValue];
            }
        }
        else {
            self.commandArguments = [NSArray arrayWithArray:commandParts];
        }
    }

    // build invoke
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(function);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:sel]) {

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:sel withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        // using invocation causes a SIGABORT because the try/catch block was not catching the exception.
        // using perform selector fixed the problem (i.e., the try/catch block now correctly catches the exception, as expected)

    }
    else {
        [appDelegate buildNewExceptionWithName:@"" andMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object does not respond to selector %@", function]];
    }

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    hasError = YES;
    [self updateErrorMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error processing command %@: %@", aCommand,  [e reason]]];
}
@finally {
    [function release];
    [commandParts release];
}

if (hasError == YES) {
    [appDelegate buildNewExceptionWithName:@"executeThisCommand" andMessage:self.errorMessage];
}
}

// this can return nil
-(NSString *)getQueryStringValue:(NSString *)name {

NSString *returnValue = nil;
if (queryString != nil) {
    returnValue = [queryString objectForKey:[name lowercaseString]];
}

return returnValue;
}
```