# what is difference between declaring variable in .m vs in .m but with category in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, objective-c-category

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instance variables declared in ObjC implementation file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785765/instance-variables-declared-in-objc-implementation-file)

I would like to know the difference in terms of visibility between the following two code snippets, i.e. where and who can access/see the variable name and all other difference as well (other than one is category).

#### 1:

```
// in implementation file SchoolTableViewController.m
@interface SchoolTableViewController()
{
NSString* name;
}

@end

@implementation SchoolTableViewController
...
@end
```

#### 2:

```
// in implementation file SchoolTableViewController.m
@implementation SchoolTableViewController
{
NSString* name;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) ,may be it will help you!

Comment: This question is not the same as the link provided with reason of duplication.  I voted to open this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think second scenario of the variable has @protected scope, whereas in first case it's visibility is limited to only the .m file