# ARC property qualifier

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, qualifiers

I'm relatively new to ARC. I'm making an `UIView` subclass, that will have two labels (title and subtitle). I don't want to publicly expose the labels as properties, only their text.

I'm currently using this:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

```
@implementation MyView
{
    UILabel *_titleLabel;
    UILabel *_subtitleLabel;
}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [_titleLabel setText:title];
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return [_titleLabel text];
}

- (void)setSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    [_subtitleLabel setText:title];
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return [_subtitleLabel text];
}

@end
```

Are my two @properties correctly declared? Should I use the `strong`, `weak` or any other qualifier? And why?

Comment: @trojanfoe: this is not my point. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785765/instance-variables-declared-in-objc-implementation-file

Comment: Actually it is legal. That's the new-ish way to declare private ivars.

Comment: Just imagine I've declared them in a private category at the top of the `.m`. It doesn't change my question.

Comment: If that's legal then that's great; but I don't see why you need the properties at all as you aren't storing their value locally; just within the `UILabel`s. Why not just declare the setter/getters instead?

Comment: Just because I want to be able to do `myView.title = @"Hello"; myView.subtitle = @"World"`. (And I wanna learn ARC, too, obviously.)

Comment: AFAIK that is ok. The only point is that I do not see the alloc/init of the UILabel objects. If they are properly created, e.g. within the init method of the view, then this should be fine.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've skipped the alloc/init for readability here. Of course, I instanciate them and lay them out at the proper places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to work with setter / getter, I think the appropiate tag would be the `readwrite`. `strong` `weak` `retain` etc apply when the property is the setter/getter for an instance variable.

Comment: So, no qualifier at all? I think I remember `readwrite` is the default.

Comment: Yeah, that's about it really. When you implement the getter/setters and you are not even storing the value in an instance variable, it doesn't really matter, specially when using ARC

Comment: Agreed. That sounds logical.

Comment: Confirmed to work. The key is effectively "no instance variable --> no lifetime/ownership qualifier". (The two labels are ivars, so by default, they're strongly owned by the class, but never exposed publicly).