# How do I define instance variable in class implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I make instance variable inside class `@implementation` in Objective-c?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785765/instance-variables-declared-in-objc-implementation-file

Comment: Reason I am asking this is because the way I tried to declare variable inside @implementation seems to produces some kind of global variable... so this question is no so stupid, so please, do not down vote, it has a syntax glitch compared to C#, java and other OOP languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in curly braces, like so:

```
@implementation {
    id anIvar;
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when variable declaration is not placed in curly braces? What kind of variable do I get?

Comment: @Dusan I think it would be technically a global variable that is only visible within either the implementation block, or perhaps the file it was defined in. I think it'd act similarly to a static variable.

Comment: Yes it seems indeed something like that. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, without the brackets its a global variable. Meaning - just once instanciated - not one for each class, slightly different syntax accessing it plus linking issues when the same "global" variable name is used in other classes. But AFAIK, the brackets follow an `@interface` key word, not `@implementation`. That may well be a "second" `@interface` within the *.m file.

Comment: You can actually put the brackets after the @implementation, I think I learned first of this from the modern obj-c session at WWDC 2012.

Comment: @Dusan You get a global variable. It's slightly different to static in that it's exposed out at linker time meaning if you have `CGFloat x;` in two `.m` files you will get a duplicate symbol linker error whereas `static CGFloat x;` in two files would give you two variables called `x`, each only visible inside it's own `.m` file. Neither of these is probably what you wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't - instance variables are defined inside `@interface` blocks.

If you want it to only be visible inside your .m file you can add this before your `@implementation`

```
@interface MyClass () {
    NSInteger myInteger;
    NSString *myString;
}
@end
```

Comment: well, I almost always put them in `@implementation {}` like Carl Veazey's answer in these days.

Comment: You can put them in the implementation block in curly braces, see the possible duplicate.

Comment: True but then if you wanted to add 'private' properties you run into problems . . . personally, I prefer the separation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in class extension in implementation file:

```
@interface SomeClass () {
    NSInteger _aVariable;
}

@end
```

Or better define a property:

```
@interface SomeClass ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger aProperty;

@end
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that in the class extension, neat.

Answer (score -2):

Define an instance variable like this:

```
NSMyClass *_nameOfObject;
```

You should to do it in your `@interface` not your `@implementation`

Comment: You can put them in your implementation block, see the possible duplicate.